# Customize Courses' grades in Moodle

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

Hello there :) I'm using Moodle e-learning software for an educational institute.

The default Letter grading in Mooodle is applied on all courses.I want to change the letter grading  based on a mathematical formula .The formula should calculated each course by it self.
for Example:
    Course Data Base:
    Max=maximum grade of course 
    Range=(max-50)/6
    F =0
    D >=45
    C >=50
    B >=50+range
    B+ >=2range+ 50
    A>=3range+50
Any help?
Many thanks

Comment: Hello huhu check [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. What have you tried?